# Create custom file type handler for Visual Studio with code generation on save

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm new in Visual Studio extension creation.
I need to create a such extension for C++ projects, which will:

- handle provided file type (by extension);
- syntax highlighting for provided file;
- code generation on file change event.

In common i need to write some information to file, handle file change event and generate a set of files. and it will be nice to add automatically all generated files to my c++ solution.

Could any one advise on is it possible in common, what should i read to make this? thanks